# How to transform the categorical feature

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I am kind of new to machine learning, and I am working on a classification/regression problem.

In the dataset, there is a weather feature takes a few categorical values, as: Sunny, Rainy, Windy, Cloudy, etc.

There are two optional ways to transform this feature,

1.Give each category a numeric index, as

```
date           weather        indexedWeather
2017-11-01      Sunny              0
2017-11-02      Cloudy             1
2017-11-03      Snow               3
2017-11-04      Cloudy             1
2017-11-05      Windy              2
2017-11-06      Sunny              0
2017-11-07      Snow               3
2017-11-08      Cloudy             1
```

*Spark MLLib has an `VectorIndexer` tranformer to do this task*

2.Tranform this feature into a binary vector:

```
date           weather         indexedWeather
2017-11-01      Sunny              1 0 0 0
2017-11-02      Cloudy             0 1 0 0
2017-11-03      Snow               0 0 1 0
2017-11-04      Cloudy             0 1 0 0
2017-11-05      Windy              0 0 0 1
2017-11-06      Sunny              1 0 0 0
2017-11-07      Snow               0 0 1 0
2017-11-08      Cloudy             0 1 0 0
```

*Spark MLLib doesn't provide a tranformer for this kind of task.*

Which one is preferred? It looks that these both two options are used in practice , but in my opinion, I would prefer the second option, but i would hear from you guys's understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second approach, there is actually a transformer in Spark that does it for you: `OneHotEncoder`. In this case, it should be used together with a `StringIndexer`, see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) for the documentation.

As for which one is more appropriate, since the weather is strictly categorical and you cannot sort them, it's more appropriate to use a binary vectors. This is true in the cases where the algorithm expects continous features and will split the data depending on the values (such as Logistic Regression). If there is **no clear rank or sortable order** that you want the algorithm to consider, then one-hot encoder should be used.